# HTML5 canvas strokeText line width showing differently when scaled

Tags: html5-canvas

I am drawing stroked text on canvas. When the canvas is scaled, the line width of the text stroke shows differently on my desktop browsers, as compared to that on iPad (Chrome/Safari).

It shows scaled width on desktop Chrome, whereas it shows un-scaled text stroke on iPad Chrome/Safari. The text size honors the scaling however.

iOS Version: 11.1.2

A stroked rect draws with the scaled stroke width on both desktop and iPad.

Here's a fiddle for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/hxyLc0ka/10/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.scale(5, 5);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

ctx.strokeRect(2, 2, 50, 40);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.strokeText("Hello", 10, 28);
```

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?